# Kind Signatures

Tags: haskell, types

I am going through the Haskell wiki books GADTS

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT guide.

I was tracking pretty well until a Kind signature was added which generalizes the constrained type of the Cons constructor.

```
data Safe
data NotSafe

data MarkedList             ::  * -> * -> * where
  Nil                       ::  MarkedList t NotSafe
  Cons                      ::  a -> MarkedList a b -> MarkedList a c

safeHead                    ::  MarkedList a Safe -> a
safeHead (Cons x _)          =  x


silly 0                      =  Nil
silly 1                      =  Cons () Nil
silly n                      =  Cons () $ silly (n-1)
```

With the Kind Signature I can use the Cons constructor to construct and pattern match against both Safe and Unsafe MarkedLists. While I understand what going on I am unfortunately having trouble building any intuition as to how the Kind Signature is allowing this. Why do I need the Kind Signature? What is the Kind Signature doing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The same way a type signature works for values, a kind signature works for types.

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Bool
f x y = x < y
```

Here, `f` takes two argument values and produces a result value.  The equivalent for types could be:

```
data D a b = D a b
```

The type `D` takes two argument types and produces a result type (it is `* -> * -> *`).  For example, `D Int String` is a type (which has kind `*`).  The partial application `D Int` has kind `* -> *`, just the same way the partial application `f 15` has type `Int -> Bool`.

So we could rewrite the above as:

```
data D :: * -> * -> * where
  D :: a -> b -> D a b
```

In GHCi, you can query types and kinds:

```
> :type f
f :: Int -> Int -> Bool
> :kind D
D :: * -> * -> *
```

Comment: Im still confused since `MarkedList a b where ...` seems to work in GHC 7.4.1 aswell. I'm not sure what the kind signature provides.

Comment: That looks like an alternate way of saying the same thing to me.

Comment: Yes, but the Kind Signature needs a language pragma while the latter does not. Why, if both ways are the same? What extra does the Kind Signature provide?

Comment: In other circumstances, you may want to specify an alternate kind.  For example, `data X a = X`.  Here, `X` has kind `* -> *` and its parameter must be nullary.  You can specify a unary kind for its parameter with `data X (a :: * -> *) = X`, so `X` would have kind `(* -> *) -> *`, so you could e.g. parameterize `X` over functors or monads or something not nullary.  I think it's not necessary in the example you stated.

Comment: Ooh, OK, Great! So like the example states the function has to carry the extra type info and we're best not to export the Cons Constructor as its too general (perhaps a smart constructor function instead?). I think I understand. Thank you Deitrich.

Comment: @ExternalReality: (re: "What extra does the Kind Signature provide?", in addition to what Dietrich Epp said) One could consider the `MarkedList a b where ...` syntax somewhat misleading in that it looks like the names `a` and `b` are bound for use in the body (after the `where`), while actually, they have no effect at all (each constructor binds its own names). Writing `MarkedList :: * -> * -> *` avoids this. Just a matter of taste, though.

Comment: Yeah, that's what functorsalad said. With gadt, the type constrctor parameters don't scope over the dqta constructor signature